# Trying to change wallpaper from batch file in USB, how to detect directory letter?

Tags: windows

Using this here:
https://www.windows-commandline.com/change-windows-wallpaper-command-line/

```
@echo off  

pushd %~d0
for /L %%a in (1,1,10) do (
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d 
"\Stuff\Bored.bmp" /f
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
exit 0          
)
```

How to add drive letter from different PCs to the directory for wallpaper image?
When i run it like this, it just puts a black background. When i add the drive letter (eg F:), the actual picture turns into the desktop background.

Comment: Tonny's comments are correct, but I think DoomMagnet wants to find the drive letter assigned to a USB drive which has the JPG or BMP files that will be used for the wallpaper. If that is the case, he can look at this SuperUser tip to use the drive letter in a batch file:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788554/find-usb-drive-letter

Comment: @DoomMagnet , what are you actually trying to do?  Are you trying to change desktop picture on other people's PCs?

Comment: I'd like to use something like 

/d "%~d0\Stuff\Bored.bmp" /f

Comment: @Davidpostill Can you undo your delete of my answer? 2nd part, that DOES answer the question fully, went missing due to ISP issues at the office. I only noticed this and fixed it 5 minutes ago when I got back online at home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
set DRIVE=%cd:~0,2%

reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d 
"%DRIVE%\Stuff\Bored.bmp" /f
```

The environmental variable `%DRIVE%` will expand as the drive letter.